# webpack 4 require is not defined

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am working on two projects inside a monorepo. Both projects have the exact same dependencies and each one has a `webpack.config.js`. The config for both is exactly the same. However, on one of the projects webpack adds a `require('../../node_modules/process/browser')` which results in the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I can't figure out why this is happening so would appreciate some new ideas and suggestions. My config looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "devtool": "eval",
        "entry": {
            "main": "index.web.js"
        },
        "mode": "development",
        "module": {
            "rules": [
                {
                    "exclude": /node_modules\/(?!(@bs)\/)/,
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "plugins": [
                            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
                        ],
                        "presets": [
                            "@babel/preset-flow",
                            [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                {
                                    "targets": "last 2 versions, not dead",
                                    "useBuiltIns": "usage"
                                }
                            ],
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ]
                    },
                    "test": /(\.jsx?|\.mjs)$/
                },
            ]
        },
        "name": "client",
        "optimization": {
            "splitChunks": {
                "cacheGroups": {
                    "commons": {
                        "chunks": "initial",
                        "enforce": true,
                        "name": "vendor",
                        "test": /node_modules\/(?!(@bs)\/)/
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "chunkFilename": "js/[name].[chunkhash].js",
            "filename": "js/[name].[chunkhash].js",
            "path": "public/build",
            "publicPath": "/build/"
        },
        "plugins": [
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
                APP_ENV: 'browser',
                CI: null,
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                chunkFilename: css/[id].[contenthash].css,
                filename: css/[name].[contenthash].css,
            }),
            new SvgStorePlugin(),
            new DotenvPlugin(),
            new ManifestPlugin(),
        ],
        "resolve": {
            "extensions": [
                ".js",
                ".jsx",
                ".mjs",
                ".scss"
            ]
        },
        "stats": {
            "children": false,
            "colors": true,
            "modules": false,
            "reasons": true
        },
        "target": "web",
        "watch": true,
        "watchOptions": {
            "ignored": /node_modules/
        }
    },
    {
        "devtool": "eval",
        "entry": {
            "main": "index.server.js"
        },
        "externals": /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/,
        "mode": "development",
        "module": {
            "rules": [
                {
                    "exclude": /node_modules\/(?!(@bs)\/)/,
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "plugins": [
                            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
                        ],
                        "presets": [
                            "@babel/preset-flow",
                            [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                {
                                    "targets": "node 8",
                                    "useBuiltIns": "usage"
                                }
                            ],
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ]
                    },
                    "test": /(\.jsx?|\.mjs)$/
                },
            ]
        },
        "name": "server",
        "output": {
            "chunkFilename": "js/[name].js",
            "filename": "js/[name].js",
            "libraryTarget": "commonjs2",
            "path": "server/build",
            "publicPath": "/build/"
        },
        "plugins": [
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
                APP_ENV: 'server',
                CI: null,
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                chunkFilename: css/[id].[contenthash].css,
                filename: css/[name].[contenthash].css,
            }),
            new SvgStorePlugin(),
            new DotenvPlugin(),
        ],
        "resolve": {
            "extensions": [
                ".js",
                ".jsx",
                ".mjs",
                ".scss"
            ]
        },
        "stats": {
            "children": false,
            "colors": true,
            "modules": false,
            "reasons": true
        },
        "target": "node",
        "watch": true,
        "watchOptions": {
            "ignored": /node_modules/
        }
    }
]
```

I noticed that when I add `type: 'javascript/auto'` to the `babel-loader` config then the problem is gone. But why? And is this the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem when webpack adds polyfils inside an .mjs file, using require funcition. I think you should use import inside an .mjs file. If you have two projects which are compiled using the same config file, and one of the them has the issue while the other is working fine, this probably means that polyfils has been added to the project with the issue.